# How to convert the ordinary jpeg image bytes to the DICOM native image bytes using C#

Tags: c#, jpeg, dicom, image-conversion

Currently I'm writing a module for the conversion of `JPEG` to `DICOM Image` Conversion. On analysis I've completed the tag rendering, now the image is not properly rendered in the `DICOM` file.

Is there any algorithm to convert the `JPEG` to `DICOM`.

Comment: We had to [roll our own](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2011/)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from Matthieu's response, here is a very simple way of creating a DICOM envelope for a JPEG stream using the excellent GDCM library and his referenced example (note I have used some helper classes, but is quite simple):

```
       ImageReader r = new ImageReader();
        gdcm.Image image = r.GetImage();
        image.SetNumberOfDimensions(2);
        DataElement pixeldata = DataElementHelper.PixelData;
        string file1 = @"D:\testfil.jpeg";

        System.IO.FileStream infile =
            new System.IO.FileStream(file1, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        //uint fsize = gdcm.PosixEmulation.FileSize(file1);

        //byte[] jstream = new byte[fsize];
        //infile.Read(jstream, 0, jstream.Length);

        byte[] jstream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file1);
        uint fsize = (uint) jstream.Length;

        SmartPtrFrag sq = SequenceOfFragments.New();
        Fragment frag = new Fragment();
        frag.SetByteValue(jstream, new gdcm.VL((uint)jstream.Length));
        sq.AddFragment(frag);
        pixeldata.SetValue(sq.__ref__());

        // insert:
        image.SetDataElement(pixeldata);


        PhotometricInterpretation pi = new PhotometricInterpretation(PhotometricInterpretation.PIType.MONOCHROME2);
        image.SetPhotometricInterpretation(pi);

        // FIXME hardcoded:
        PixelFormat pixeltype = new PixelFormat(PixelFormat.ScalarType.UINT8);
        image.SetPixelFormat(pixeltype);

        TransferSyntax ts = new TransferSyntax(TransferSyntax.TSType.JPEGBaselineProcess1);
        image.SetTransferSyntax(ts);

        image.SetDimension(0, (uint)1700);
        image.SetDimension(1, (uint)2200);

        ImageWriter writer = new ImageWriter();
        gdcm.File file = writer.GetFile();


        var ds = file.GetDataSet();
        DataElement patientID = DataElementHelper.PatientID;
        DataElement patientName = DataElementHelper.PatientName;
        DataElement accessionNumber = DataElementHelper.AccessionNumber;
        DataElement studyDate = DataElementHelper.StudyDate;
        DataElement studyTime = DataElementHelper.StudyTime;
        DataElement studyInstanceUID = DataElementHelper.StudyInstanceUID;
        DataElement seriesInstanceUID = DataElementHelper.SeriesInstanceUID;
        DataElement mediaStorage = DataElementHelper.SOPClassUID;

        string studyUID = new gdcm.UIDGenerator().Generate();
        string seriesUID = new gdcm.UIDGenerator().Generate();

        //pixelData.SetArray(b, (uint)b.Length);
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref patientName, "TEST^MARCUS");
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref patientID, "0000000801");
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref accessionNumber, "0000000801-12345");
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref studyDate, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref studyTime, DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"));
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref studyInstanceUID, studyUID);
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref seriesInstanceUID, seriesUID);
        DataElementHelper.SetDataElement(ref mediaStorage, "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7");
        ds.Insert(patientID);
        ds.Insert(patientName);
        ds.Insert(accessionNumber);
        ds.Insert(studyDate);
        ds.Insert(studyTime);
        ds.Insert(studyInstanceUID);
        ds.Insert(seriesInstanceUID);
        ds.Insert(mediaStorage);

        writer.SetImage(image);
        writer.SetFileName("gdcm_test.dcm");
        bool ret = writer.Write();
```

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at the [mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm) C# DICOM library, originally written by Colby Dillion. He has developed managed C++ "bridges" to the [IJG/LibJPEG](http://www.ijg.org/) and [OpenJPEG](http://code.google.com/p/openjpeg/) code bases, so mdcm provides both 8/12/16-bit lossy and lossless JPEG support as well as JPEG-2000 support.

Colby's original library has WinForms dependencies. I have created a Silverlight and WPF targeted fork of mdcm [here](https://github.com/cureos/mdcm). The WPF version of the library can fully utilize the same JPEG(-2000) codecs that Colby originally implemented.
The Silverlight version on the other hand currently cannot benefit from these codecs. I have made some attempts to apply the [FJCore](http://code.google.com/p/fjcore/) and [LibJpeg.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/) libraries for lossy JPEG support in Silverlight, but these libraries only support 8-bit images at the moment.

Regards,
Anders @ Cureos

Comment: I would appreciate it if whoever downvoted this answer could explain why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in .NET itself for DICOM support. You will need to use a library. I do not know of any free ones but I have used LeadTools and it will do it (for a price). But I would only give it a 4/10, and I would recommenced you look for other options too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'convert' JPEG to DICOM. DICOM is simply an 'envelope' for your JPEG stream. Here is what I did in GDCM to encapsulate (= put into a DICOM envelope) an existing MPEG2 file:

http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/MpegVideoInfo_8cs-example.html

Simply adapt that code for an input JPEG file. For instance have a look at:

http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/DecompressJPEGFile_8cs-example.html

No need to decompress/recompress, that would be a waste of resource.